# MonoDroid JQueryUI or HTML

Tags: c#, html, jquery-mobile, xamarin.android

I am developing a app using Monodroid (C#) and wanted to some good looking UI controls (ex: jquery). I am not even sure if it is possible!! I don't see any samples and I even tried to google it..

I found this link: http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2011/09/18/how-to-include-jquery-mobile-in-monodroid-project.aspx  But author said it won't work in Android.

any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of Mono for Android to use the native UI controls instead of tools like JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got a chance to look at JQuery Mobile? http://jquerymobile.com/

That might just be the tool you are looking for.

Comment: Yes. Did you visit the link I posted? Author said it won't work in Android. Also, do you know where to add the html code in C# Android application??

Comment: Oh totally missed that. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow your link, then it provides simple instructions for how to make it work - it looks like you simply need to change the case of some of the include urls.

> To make it working change all of them as shown below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquerymobile/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>
```